# Running a python web service on heroku

Tags: python, heroku, shelve

I have a Python-flask web service which is running absolutely fine on my localhost server. Now I have deployed it on heroku and it doesn't run when I try to access it from heroku showing me that application has some errors. I tested it on localhost(and confirmed that the web service runs absolutely fine) and then deployed it on heroku. I am using a shelve file from which my web service retrieves the persistent data. When it runs on localhost it runs fine but I think at heroku it fails to retrieve the contents of my shelve file. In my earlier web service that I had deployed on Heroku I used to create new shelve file on every run but in this web service I have already created shelve file with persistent data loaded in it and my web service just refers to this data without writing anything to it.

Here is my web service script:

```
news_index=shelve.open('IndexedMapping')

item = [] # list for storing the final results

with open('TodaysToiScrapedItemsOutput.json') as f: #load json file
    data = json.load(f)

input_headline = news_string
input_headline_list =  input_headline.split()
temp_input_headline_list = []

for each_word in input_headline_list:
    temp_input_headline_list.append(each_word)


for each_word in temp_input_headline_list:
    if (each_word.lower() in ignore_this_words):
        input_headline_list.remove(each_word)

hit_cnt=0
key_and_hit_cnt_dict={}
for each_key in news_index:
    for each_word in input_headline_list:
    if(each_word.lower() in each_key):
        hit_cnt = hit_cnt + 1   
    key_and_hit_cnt_dict[each_key] = hit_cnt
    hit_cnt=0

sorted_keys_wrt_hitcnt = sorted(key_and_hit_cnt_dict, key= key_and_hit_cnt_dict.__getitem__,reverse=True)


i=0
for each_entry in sorted_keys_wrt_hitcnt:
    if(i<5):
        location=news_index[each_entry]
        item.append({ 'body' : data[location]["body"],'location':location,'key':each_entry,'words':input_headline_list})
    i = i+1   

return jsonify({'item':item})
```

**EDIT**

This is my log

```
2014-03-19T10:09:08.000898+00:00 app[web.1]: 2014-03-19 10:09:07 [7] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 7
2014-03-19T10:09:08.262376+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to up
2014-03-19T10:09:18.149027+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path=/ host=glacial-  plateau-3427.herokuapp.com request_id=203107b5-5c0e-40bd-8e0b-4cdc8649c2f1 fwd="27.251.95.162" dyno=web.1 connect=2ms service=25ms status=404 bytes=384
2014-03-19T10:09:24.995531+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path=/toi/cricket host=glacial-plateau-3427.herokuapp.com request_id=18d612f6-7cf6-4fc0-a686-6a8680cf469f fwd="27.251.95.162" dyno=web.1 connect=2ms service=18ms status=500 bytes=454
2014-03-19T10:10:45.866027+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path=/toi/cricket%20India%20T20 host=glacial-plateau-3427.herokuapp.com request_id=5122179a-dfde-4a22-b916-daa7eec3ec10 fwd="27.251.95.162" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=6ms status=500 bytes=454
2014-03-19T10:13:39.713629+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path=/toi/aap%20modi%20kejriwal host=glacial-plateau-3427.herokuapp.com request_id=0426e03c-61bd-4b4f-995b-55a72c91d676 fwd="27.251.95.162" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=5ms status=500 bytes=454
```

Comment: What error you are getting.. can you show your heroku logs? Also whether this shelve file is in git or you generate it dynamically?

Comment: Do you know that Heroku dynos have a completely ephemeral filesytem? https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/dynos#isolation-and-security

Comment: @anuragal Shelve file is in git... Its already filled with data and not generated dynamically....

Comment: @aychedee got your point...but its working the same way in my earlier heroku application only the change there that application doesn't use any shelve file to read but it still uses a shelve to write the indexed data..

Comment: What error you are getting...  can you show your heroku logs?

Comment: @anuragal sorry but totally clueless about heroku logs.....where do I get it..?

Comment: on heroku git command prompt type `heroku logs`, this will give you the current logs.

Comment: Heroku is returning 500 error. That means some problem in processing the request. I will suggest to put some debug\print statements and try-except in your code and try again. Also I can see one more file you are loading into your code i.e. `TodaysToiScrapedItemsOutput.json` is it in your git repo or generated dynamically?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/50017/discussion-between-y-dixit-and-anuragal)

Answer (score 1):

As discussed over chat

- All files you are accessing in code are in git
- You are not modifying any file from your code
- Getting 500 error when running the code

In my opinion you should check your code, it might be generating some exception which are unhandled right now. What you can do is to wrap your code inside try-except block and print the exception. like-

```
try:
    news_index=shelve.open('IndexedMapping')

    item = [] # list for storing the final results

    with open('TodaysToiScrapedItemsOutput.json') as f: #load json file
        data = json.load(f)

    input_headline = news_string
    input_headline_list =  input_headline.split()
    temp_input_headline_list = []

    for each_word in input_headline_list:
        temp_input_headline_list.append(each_word)


    for each_word in temp_input_headline_list:
        if (each_word.lower() in ignore_this_words):
            input_headline_list.remove(each_word)

    hit_cnt=0
    key_and_hit_cnt_dict={}
    for each_key in news_index:
        for each_word in input_headline_list:
            if(each_word.lower() in each_key):
                hit_cnt = hit_cnt + 1   
            key_and_hit_cnt_dict[each_key] = hit_cnt
        hit_cnt=0

    sorted_keys_wrt_hitcnt = sorted(key_and_hit_cnt_dict, key= key_and_hit_cnt_dict.__getitem__,reverse=True)


    i=0
    for each_entry in sorted_keys_wrt_hitcnt:
        if(i<5):
            location=news_index[each_entry]
            item.append({ 'body' : data[location]["body"],'location':location,'key':each_entry,'words':input_headline_list})
        i = i+1

    return jsonify({'item':item})
except Exception, e:
    import traceback
    traceback.print_exc()
    return jsonify({'error': str(e)})
```